# How does boost sort handle additional memory allocation=

Tags: c++, boost, dynamic-memory-allocation

According to the documentation of `boost::sort` (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/sort/doc/html/index.html) all algorithms uses "*additional memory*".

I couldn't find any information on how this memory is allocated in the documentation.

Does anyone know if it is *dynamically heap-allocated using new* during each sort operation, is it *stack-space*, or does boost::sort utilize some *dynamic internal temporary memory buffer* (like `std::stable_sort` used to utilize `std::get_temporary_buffer` in C++11)?

If heap-allocated, is it possible to pass a pre-allocated buffer to the sort operations in order to gain control over memory allocations?

Comment: `std::stable_sort` does dynamic allocation: "This function attempts to allocate a temporary buffer equal in size to the sequence to be sorted. If the allocation fails, the less efficient algorithm is chosen."

Comment: If it's O(N) memory or worse, then it practically cannot be stack memory as it could then only be used for "small" sequences.

Comment: @Caleth Thats what I meant, will rewrite.